# Unexpected token ILLEGAL with hightcharts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use highchart in vb.net. When I launch ***ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock*** chrome return ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL***

VB code:

```
    Dim Script As String
    Script = "$(function () {\n"
    Script += "$('#container').highcharts({\n"
    Script += "chart: {\n"
    Script += "type: 'line'\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "title: {\n"
    Script += "text: 'Consumos por semanas'\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "subtitle: {\n"
    Script += "text: 'Kwh/Módulos-Piezas'\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "xAxis: {\n"
    Script += "categories: ['25', '26']\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "yAxis: {\n"
    Script += "title: {\n"
    Script += "text: 'Kwh'\n"
    Script += "}\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "plotOptions: {\n"
    Script += "line: {\n"
    Script += "dataLabels: {\n"
    Script += "enabled: true\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "enableMouseTracking: false\n"
    Script += "}\n"
    Script += "},\n"
    Script += "series: [{\n"
    Script += "name: 'cach',\n"
    Script += "data: [1.1003, 6.5265]},\n"
    Script += "]\n"
    Script += "});\n"
    Script += "});"

    Dim popupScript = "<script type='text/javascript'>" + Script + "</script>"
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "onload", popupScript, False)
```

aspx code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

If I export the script variable to txt file and replace \n with newline and put the code in [hightchart demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/), it works. 
If I paste the code in a function javascript directly in aspx file, it works.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that '**\n**' is not the right way to define a new line in a VB string.  That would have worked in C# but not VB.NET.  You want to use the vbCrLf constant.

Also, you shouldn't build a string using repeated concatinations when it can be defined in one statement.

```
  Dim Script As String = "$(function () {" & vbCrLf &
       "$('#container').highcharts({" & vbCrLf &
       "chart: {" & vbCrLf &
       "type: 'line'" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "title: {" & vbCrLf &
       "text: 'Consumos por semanas'" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "subtitle: {" & vbCrLf &
       "text: 'Kwh/Módulos-Piezas'" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "xAxis: {" & vbCrLf &
       "categories: ['25', '26']" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "yAxis: {" & vbCrLf &
       "title: {" & vbCrLf &
       "text: 'Kwh'" & vbCrLf &
       "}" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "plotOptions: {" & vbCrLf &
       "line: {" & vbCrLf &
       "dataLabels: {" & vbCrLf &
       "enabled: true" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "enableMouseTracking: false" & vbCrLf &
       "}" & vbCrLf &
       "}," & vbCrLf &
       "series: [{" & vbCrLf &
       "name: 'cach'," & vbCrLf &
       "data: [1.1003, 6.5265]}," & vbCrLf &
       "]" & vbCrLf &
       "});" & vbCrLf &
       "});"
```

Comment: A lot of thanks¡¡¡¡ it's works but it's only "& vbCrLf" not "& vbCrLf &"